# Data binding in mat-select of angular materials does not work

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular 6 and angular material for front page of my application, and I have a module called Roles which has a collection of Permissions associated with it, on Roles page, I have an edit button which on clicking retrieves the role by its id and the role has a collection of permissions associated with it, as you can see in image below:[image: the role object has <code>allPermissions</code> and <code>permission</code> collection in it] when I click on edit button, a pop-up appears, which is an angular material form and among other fields, it has the following field:

```
<div>
    <mat-form-field class="form" floatPlaceholder="never" shouldPlaceholderFloat="false">
     <mat-select [(ngModel)] = "data.permissions" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" multiple>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let permission of data.allPermissions" [value]="permission.name">
         {{permission.name}}
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

its expected that the `permissions` array should be pre-populated in mat-select drop-down because i have binded it with `[(ngModel)] = "data.permissions"`, but it does not, as you can see in the second image

[image: the drop-down does not have permissions pre-populated].

Any help will be highly appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change that you need:

> First:

Use `[compareWith]="compareFn"` in HTML and TS  Code:

```
compareFn(c1,c2): boolean {
  return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```

> Second:

For `mat-option` set `[value]` to  `permission` like:

```
[value]="permission"
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <mat-form-field class="form" floatPlaceholder="never" shouldPlaceholderFloat="false">
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="data.permissions" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" multiple [compareWith]="compareFn">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let permission of data.allPermissions" [value]="permission">
                {{permission.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-compare-function-with-matselect)

Comment: THANKS @Prashant, it works, thank you soooo much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will let of permission on permissions, when you select an option you can catch an event to get the id from the name of the item you selected..

**The Code:**

```
<div>
  <mat-form-field class="form" floatPlaceholder="never" shouldPlaceholderFloat="false">
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="data.permissions" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let permission of data.permissions" [value]="permission.name">
        {{ permission.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

`NgModel` is a item.name of allpermissions. You put permission array to this, how to display?

Comment: You want to show permissions array and choose a item in allpermissions push to it? Or mean? Please describe detail for your case.